# How to send AWS SMS messages to multiple phone numbers in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I've managed to get my SNS service working in PHP laravel but the issue I have is that I can only send to one number.

I've used the following:

```
$sms = AWS::createClient('sns');
    $sms->publish([
        'Message' => $content,
        'PhoneNumber' => '+123456789',
        'MessageAttributes' => [
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType'  => [
                'DataType'    => 'String',
                'StringValue' => 'Transactional',
            ]
        ],
    ]);
```

The phone number has to be a string, I really do not want to put this inside a for loop for each number and I can't find anything using PHP specifically about sending to multiple phone numbers. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not a PHP feature you should be looking for is whether amazon supports sending SMS to multiple phone numbers via SNS. From what I've looked at so far it doesn't seem to but I may be wrong

Comment: It is possible via creating a pub/sub topic, subscribing all the numbers to it and then publishing but I can't seem to find a way to do this in PHP unless you can't do it in PHP

Comment: I think you can use comma separated phone numbers.

Comment: There's the [Subscribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sns-2010-03-31.html#subscribe) method but it doesn't seem straight-forward. You probably need to subscribe users when they register and then you can publish to a list at a later time

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys so for anyone interested I managed to find a way to do this. I create a Job queue which I passed the array of phone numbers as well as the content of the message, and then in the handle method in the job just looped through the phone numbers with my above method and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Do you run in a sms push limit in your queue? I try it for 100.000 sms in one job. Do you have some experiance to share?